# How do I fix "before you can record we need access to your documents folder" in Win 10 Voice Recorder?

Tags: windows-10, audio

It looks like I have full control of my Documents folder, so I can't figure out why Voice Recorder wouldn't be able to write to it:

[image: security for my Documents folder]

[image: error message]

I tried "Reset" option in control panel for this program (seems like I can't uninstall it, that option is disabled).

Comment: The users folder is not the documents folder ...

Comment: well the error message says Documents and the Documents folder is inside the Users folder; the owner of my Documents folder is me and I have full control (same as Users/Justin folder)

Answer (score 0):

I referenced [this reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/windows/comments/6dsz3i/voice_recorder_wont_let_me_record/) because A) it's relevant, and B) the suggestions make sense.

Your security looks fine, but for the sake of humoring the OS, change the owner of Documents to "Everyone, and add a usergroup also named "Everyone" with full control.

Since the logical problems with voice recorder not being able to write to documents are solved, I would go to guess that there's a problem with windows' own system files.
Open up command prompt, run these commands, in order, but stop after one throws an error. (Record their output please)

1. `sfc /scannow`
2. `Dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth`

Comment: "change the owner of Documents to Everyone" -- but there are other users on this computer and I don't want to give them access to my Documents

Comment: I did the sfc scan and the dism command and then restarted. No change.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Documents folder and right click there to open properties. In properties, go to security and click `Edit` button then, check the `Full Control` allow button. Then you just need to click apply and Ok. There you go. This should solve the problem.
[Link to Image solving the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YcXs3.png)